# Is it possible to Test siebel open UI application using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, siebel

I would like to know. Is there any way where I can interact with Siebel application using Selenium JavaScript? Any add on required?

Comment: Can you give us a clue about Siebel, otherwise you may never get an answer? If it involves web applications, then surely yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you ensure that the Siebel Open UI Test Automation capability is enabled on the server, three additional Siebel OUI specific properties are made available for UI objects in the HTML. Those properties are:

**rn** - Repository Name - the unique name assigned to the UI object by your Siebel developers.

**un** - UI Name - name or caption of object as it appears in the UI.

**ot** - Object Type - type of object that the HTML element represents.

By using an object's **rn** property to uniquely identify the various UI elements that your tests need to interact with and verify, you should be able to build automated tests using Selenium.

I have successfully deployed an automated build acceptance and regression test suite for an enterprise Siebel Open UI based CRM using Ruby, Capybara, and Selenium-Webdriver. Those automated tests are integrated with a Jenkins CI server and are executed on a nightly basis.

The automated tests can be executed against Chrome, Firefox, Safari, or IE web browser running on OS X or Windows platforms, and can also be executed against emulated iOS or Android mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I have automated Classic Siebel application using QTP10 and it worked alright.
However, with Selenium WebDriver I was not able to automate because classic Siebel does not have a proper HTML code for Selenium WebDriver to access and control in the browser.

After reading through the documents on Siebel Open UI I believe that proper HTML code will be visible in the browser. If the HTML code is available, Selenium can automate the application !!

A quick google search returned the following result on the topic -http://www.tricentis.com/enterprise-solutions/solving-the-top-three-challenges-with-siebel-open-ui/, http://www.boxfusionconsulting.com/boxfusion-blog/siebel-open-ui-automated-testing/

If the HTML code is not available, you can also look at providing javascript hooks from your Siebel aplication and then use Selenium to execute the Javascript code. The same principle is used in automating flash using Selenium. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_selenium.html, https://code.google.com/archive/p/flash-selenium/. This is a long shot but worth a try!!